# Inequalities on real numbers

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, z_1, z_2$ be non-negative real numbers and $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ be positive integers such that
$$\frac{x_1}{a_1} \geq \frac{y_1}{1} \geq \frac{z_1}{b_1} \ \text{ and } \ \frac{x_2}{a_2} \geq \frac{y_2}{1} \geq \frac{z_2}{b_2}.$$
It is also given that $a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2$ and $z_1 \geq z_2$.

Is the following inequality always true?
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + y_1}{a_1 + a_2 + 1} \geq \frac{z_1 + z_2 + y_2}{b_1 + b_2 + 1}$$

Note that if $z_1 \geq z_2$ is not given as a condition, then the inequality is **false**: a counterexample is such that
$$\frac{2}{4} \geq \frac{0.5}{1} \geq \frac{1}{2} \ \text{ and } \ \frac{1}{1} \geq \frac{1}{1} \geq \frac{5}{5},$$
but
$$\frac{2 + 1 + 0.5}{4 + 1 + 1} < \frac{1 + 5 + 1}{2 + 5 + 1}.$$

Comment: I posted an in correct answer and then deleted. Where is the motivation of this come from ?

Comment: @dezdichado It is from a somewhat unrelated research question, where having some insights to the answer to this question will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:
$$\frac31\ge\frac31\ge\frac93,\qquad\frac33\ge\frac11\ge\frac11,$$
$$1+3=3+1, \ \text{ and } \ 9\ge1$$
but
$$\frac{3+3+3}{1+3+1}<\frac{9+1+1}{3+1+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample! It is indeed correct.

Comment: 1) You are welcome but please [don't thank by a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). 2) Yes, I know ;-)...